# Main.dart is not recognising as as .dart file in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

In flutter project, main.dart is not recognizing as .dart file in android studio as shown in the screenshot attached. If I change the name of the file then it's recognizing.[click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r04VK.png)

Comment: if you change to other name, it works?

Comment: Yes, If I change the name it works

Comment: Did you try changing to dark theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me that the IDE is incorrectly associating your file as a Text file.

1. Go to File -> Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)
2. Search for "File Types"
3. Look for Text in the list
4. Check if there is no entry for "main.dart" in the Text Type association.
5. If so, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work was by doing the following (on Android Studio for MacOS):

- on the main.dart file, right click and click on `Override File Type`
- in the list that appears, select: Dart

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, fixed it by right click the file and select the `Override File Type` menu, in the popup file type menu, select the dart or whatever the really file type you needed.